# SQL - Count Records and insert results into another table

Tags: sql

I have 3 databases.

```
DB1 - I need to count the rows in Table2.column1 by RefNum from DB3
DB2 - Use the count from DB1 to update List table, QtyAdd column
DB3 - contains a RefNum that both DB1 and DB2 use.
```

The following query will do the count from DB1 and update the QtyAdd column in DB2.
What I cannot figure out is how to use the RefNum from DB3 to add to the SELECT statement and the UPDATE section.

```
UPDATE List
SET QtyAdd = i.QTY
FROM (Select COUNT (Column1) AS QTY FROM DB2.dbo.Table2 WHERE (Column1 LIKE 'A%') and (RefNum = '2833')) i
WHERE (RefNum = '2833')

//Works but the RefNum is manually put in
//I have tried the following with no luck:

UPDATE List
SET QtyAdd = i.QTY
FROM (Select COUNT (Column1) AS QTY FROM DB2.dbo.Table2 WHERE (Column1 LIKE 'A%') and (RefNum = DB3.dbo.Ref.Refnum)) i
WHERE (RefNum = DB3.dbo.Ref.Refnum')
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `GROUP BY` in your subquery, and then `JOIN` to your other tables accordingly.  Something like this:

```
UPDATE L
SET QtyAdd = i.QTY
FROM List L JOIN 
    (SELECT RefNum, COUNT(Column1) AS QTY 
     FROM DB2.dbo.Table2 
     WHERE Column1 LIKE 'A%'
     GROUP BY RefNum) i ON L.RefNum = i.RefNum JOIN 
    DB3.dbo.Ref r ON l.RefNum = r.RefNum
```

- [Condensed Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c8d48/1)